# Altering python code to get rid of exec() and eval()

Tags: python, dataframe, exec, eval

I am new to python and am trying to improve a code's readability as well as speed by removing the recurrent use of exec() and eval(). However it is not obvious to me how I need to alter to code to obtain this.

I want the program to make dataframes and arrays with names based on input. Let's say that the input is like this:

```
A=[Red, Blue]
B=[Banana, Apple]
C=[Pie, Cake]
```

Then the code will then make a dataframe with a name based on each combination of input:
Red_Banana_Pie, Red_Banana_Cake, Red_Apple_Pie, Red_Apple_Cake, etc. by looping through the three lists.

```
for color in A[0:len(A)]: 
    for fruit in B[0:len(B)]: 
        for type in C[0:len(C)]:
```

And then in each loop:

```
exec('DataFr_'+color+'_'+fruit+'_'+type+'=pd.DataFrame((Data),columns=[\'Title1\',\'Title2\'])')
```

How can I do this without the exec command?

Comment: `for color in A:`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `exec('DataFr_'+color+'_'+fruit+'_'+type+'=pd.DataFrame((Data),columns=[\'Title1\',\'Title2\'])')`, you will get 8 DataFrames that has different names. But I don't recommend this because you have to use `eval()` every time you want to access to your DataFrame.(otherwise you can hardcode that, but that's really bad thing)

I think you need multi-dimensional dictionary for dataframe.

When the input is

```py
A=["Red", "Blue"]
B=["Banana", "Apple"]
C=["Pie", "Cake"]
```

[+] additionally, you'll basically get user input as `string` in python.(like `"hello, world!"`)

```py
data_set = {}
for color in A:
    data_set.update({color:{}})
    for fruit in B: 
        data_set[color].update({fruit:{}})
        for type in C:
            data_set[color][fruit].update({type:pd.DataFrame((Data),columns=['Title1','Title2'])})
                                                     # I think you have some Data in other place, right?
```

[+] moreover, you can iterate List without `[0:len(A)]` in python.

Then you can use each DataFrame by `data_set['Red']['Banana']['Cake']`.(your implementation will be `data_set[A[0]][B[0]][C[1]]`)
Then you can dynamically create DataFrame for each color, fruit, type without eval, and access to them without hardcoded value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to implement this!